# How do I import/build this project?

Tags: android, android-studio, project

I am not a dev, but have some dev experience. I have never used Android Studio before but I wanted to look at an example app.  I picked one I am very interested in, but it gives me nothing but grief just trying to import it.

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

**Notes**:

1. I am using the latest version of Android Studio. (1.0.2).  I have added in all the SDK files needed I think.
2. I have downloaded and un-zipped Gradle 2.2.1.
3. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.
4. I have dealt with Eclipse for Android previously and was able to
   hack someone else's code to suit my needs and actually deploy an unsigned apk.
5. The readme/install directions at the github don't really help a noob
   like me.

**Install**:

1. I have extracted the project from the Download Zip link.
2. For the actual import into Android Studio I choose "Open an Existing
   Android Studio Project" - because it looks like one.
3. I then choose the root directory created by unzipping the zip file,
   in this case it is named "android-beacon-library-reference-master".
4. But it seems to select the project's Gradle subfolder (/gradle) for the project!  Which I'm quite certain is invalid.  I cannot seem to get it to use the root
   folder.

What am I missing?  Or is this not the correct way to "import" this particular app?  Is this app not compatible with AS 1.0.2?.

TIA!

Comment: It is not an Android Studio project, insofar as the repo does not have Android Studio metadata files. AFAIK, you will rarely, if ever, open an existing Android Studio project unless you imported it previously (or created it yourself in Android Studio). Go through File > Import Project instead, and I think that you will have better luck.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare!  Technically I selected "Import Non-Android Studio Project" and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
1.Click Import Non-Android Studio project.
2.Locate the project you exported from Github, expand it, select the build.gradle file and click OK.
3.In the following dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)
Android Studio properly updates the project structure and creates the appropriate Gradle build file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try "Import Project" instead "Open Project". Thanks.